# Have issue accessing Google Chrome from Windows 8: Explorer cannot then locate DEFAULT folder: any answers, please?

Tags: windows-8.1

seeking to create a new browser user profile after inability to access Google Chrome on Win 8.1 Where is DEFAULT folder in Explorer directory window?

Comment: looking for this **%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Chrome, which --user-data-dir flag.
I always recommend it, becuase it will make Chrome more portable

### Example

```
chrome.exe "--user-data-dir=c:\mychromedata"
```

Comment: I suggest that anyone who can't find a directory using Windows Explorer is not going to be able to use a command line, or even know what that is.